# Get the intersection of three arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, reduce

I need to make a utility that checks the intersection of 3 arrays.
Here's my implementation in JS:

```
function intersection(array1, array2, array3) {    
    let intermediateList = [];
    let intermediateList2 = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        if (!(array2.indexOf(array1[i]) == -1)) {
            intermediateList.push(array1[i]);
        }        
        for (let j = 0; j < intermediateList.length; j++) {
            if (!(intermediateList.indexOf(array3[j]) == -1)) {
                intermediateList2.push(intermediateList[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    let endList = [ ...intermediateList, ...intermediateList2];
    return endList;    
}

intersection([5, 10, 15, 20], [15, 88, 1, 5, 7], [1, 10, 15, 5, 20])
//  [5, 15] /--> fine

intersection([5, 10, 15, 20, 40, 32], [32, 15, 88, 1, 5, 7, 40], [1, 10, 15, 5, 20, 40, 32])
// [5, 15, 40, 32, undefined, undefined, undefined] /--> can someone spot why do I get those undefined values?
```

How would you implement this with `reduce`?

Comment: It depends on how duplicate values should be handled

Comment: Please move this over to [code reviews](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: hint: `function intersect3(a, b, c) { return intersect2(a, intersect2(b, c)); }`

Comment: You can expand this to any number of arrays `const intersectN = (a, b, ...c) => !c.length ? intersect2(a, b) : intersectN(intersect2(a, b), ...c);` (should work with tail optimisation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function has a nested `for` loop which iterates the intermediateList every time where the outer loop is running. Then you push a value with index `i` instead of index `j`, but this should work only if the two for loops are not nested but chained.

```js
function intersection(array1, array2, array3) {
    let intermediateList = [];
    let intermediateList2 = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        if (array2.indexOf(array1[i]) !== -1) {
            intermediateList.push(array1[i]);
        }
    }
    for (let j = 0; j < intermediateList.length; j++) {
        if (array3.indexOf(intermediateList[j]) !== -1) {
            intermediateList2.push(intermediateList[j]);
        }
    }
    return intermediateList2;
}

console.log(intersection([5, 10, 15, 20], [15, 88, 1, 5, 7], [1, 10, 15, 5, 20]));
console.log(intersection([5, 10, 15, 20, 40, 32], [32, 15, 88, 1, 5, 7, 40], [1, 10, 15, 5, 20, 40, 32]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You could reduce the arguments and return a single array with common values.

```js
const intersection = (...array) => array.reduce((a, b) => a.filter(v => b.includes(v)));

console.log(intersection([5, 10, 15, 20], [15, 88, 1, 5, 7], [1, 10, 15, 5, 20]));
console.log(intersection([5, 10, 15, 20, 40, 32], [32, 15, 88, 1, 5, 7, 40], [1, 10, 15, 5, 20, 40, 32]));
```

Comment: very nicely put.